# Having trouble getting webapi selfhost working with ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to get Ninject to work with a project that is using self a hosted WebApi connection.

I've installed the nuget package Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Self Host (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost) along with Ninject.Web.Common.Selfhost.

The console app seems to load up correctly, but I only seem to get a connection error when hitting my URL (http://localhost:8081/api/hello). I have a similar test app that is not using Ninject that works correctly.

I'm trying to follow this post: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-self-hosted-web-application

Am I missing something to get this going? I originally tried using the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost but could not get it functioning because of various errors. If this is what I need to be using, I can revisit this.

```
public class HelloController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webApiConfiguration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8081");
        webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        var mSelfHost = new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(CreateKernel, webApiConfiguration);
        mSelfHost.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var mKernel = new StandardKernel();
        mKernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        return mKernel;
    }
}
```

Here are the packages I have installed:

```
<packages>
     <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
     <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
     <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
     <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.Selfhost" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Postman just returns this... 
Could not get any response
This seems to be like an error connecting to http://localhost:8081/api/hello. The response status was 0.

Comment: Have you tried fiddler?

Comment: Just did. I think it's just not starting up for some reason. I have to missing an obvious step. I get this: [Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. <br />Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). <br />System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8081

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding Ninject.Web.WebApi.SelfHost first. This loaded the appropriate WebApi packages automatically. Before I was loading the WebApi packages myself and then adding Ninject.